# An ł (that is, slashed l) in Euler Math?

Tags: euler

I'm using the Euler font (with the help of the `eulervm` package). I'd like to use the Polish letter "ł" (`\l`) *in an equation* (as a joke).  However, Euler obviously does not have such a character.  Are there any suggestions on how to achieve that in a visually pleasing way? `\textit{\l}` won't work (I'm using Pagella for the text font).

Currently, my go-to idea is to draw the little slash using TikZ.  (I will only need this glyph in two or three places, so it won't e.g. slow processing down a lot.)

Comment: So, you have already succeeded in using Ti*k*Z for that?

Comment: Not yet - if I decide to go that way, I will post my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the “lslashslash” glyph, that's available in the OT1 encoding.

Different kerning is needed for the various styles, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lmath}{%
  \l@math@kern{+}%
  \text{\rlap{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\@xxxii}}%
  \l@math@kern{-}%
  l%
}
\newcommand{\l@math@kern}[1]{%
  \mathchoice{\mkern#10.4mu}{\mkern#10.4mu}{\mkern#11.3mu}{\mkern#12.75mu}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\lmath_{\lmath_{\lmath}}$ 

$x\lmath y$ x\l y

$xly$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the internal `\@xxxii` that produces the stroke of `\l` in maths mode using `\text`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\lslash
  {%
    \text{\rlap{\kern.03em\@xxxii}}l%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\lslash$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the slash to be a bit thicker and longer you can use the one from the bold typeface:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\lslash
  {%
    \text{\rlap{\kern.02em\textbf{\@xxxii}}}l%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\lslash$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is really nice, although the slash produced has a similar problem to the one in the CM fonts: it's very small, almost invisible... I'll give it a try and see.

Comment: Wow, it's much better now, thanks again!